# Which package is this document using for frames and boxes?

Tags: boxes, context

The following [document](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rvhassel/Onderwijs/Tensor-ConTeX-Bib/Translated_Tensor.pdf) (pdf) uses ConTeXt. The [source file](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rvhassel/Onderwijs/Tensor-ConTeX-Bib/Tensor-ConTeXt-101031/) is too complicated for me to understand and I don't really know ConTeXt. Does anyone know what equivalent LaTeX packages generate similar frameboxes?

Comment: You can use the package `tikz` to create your own environment.

Comment: There are two possible questions here: 1) How to get the boxes using ConTeXt and 2) how to get the same effect in LaTeX. The text of the question suggests (2), but the tags given suggest (1). Am I correct in thinking that (2) is what is required? (I'm not sure I really like such a box-heavy design, but that's another matter.)

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry for the ambiguity. It is (2) I intended. I also agree that an entire document with boxes is overkill, but I felt it would be good when used sparingly in for highlights.

Comment: @Joseph: I'm quite sure that I don't like this layout. And I also find this round boxes quite horrible. They draw the eye to the frame instead to the content - which contradicts the aim of "highlighting".

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, I'll answer how to draw such boxes in ConTeXt. The oval boxes are obtained using the metafun macro `superellipsed`. The rest is just boilerplate code to pass information from TeX to Metapost and back.

```
\startuseMPgraphic{ovalbox}
  begingroup ;
  save p; path p;
  p := OverlayBox superellipsed 0.9 ;

  fill p withcolor OverlayColor;
  draw p 
      withpen pencircle scaled OverlayLineWidth 
      withcolor OverlayLineColor;
  endgroup;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[ovalbox][\useMPgraphic{ovalbox}]

\defineframedtext
    [ovalbox]
    [
      frame=off,
      width=broad,
      background=ovalbox, % overlay defined using \defineoverlay
      framecolor=red, % OverlayLineColor 
      backgroundcolor=lightgray, % OverlayColor
      rulethickness=2pt, % OverlayLineWidth
    ]

\defineenumeration
    [definition]
    [
      text=Definition , 
      location=serried,
      width=fit, 
      distance=0.5em,
      before=\startovalbox, % Add frame around definitions
      after=\stopovalbox,   % ....
    ]
```

after this

```
\startdefinition
....
\stopdefinition
```

will have an oval frame around it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The *tcolorbox* package ([see here](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf)) gives you a LaTeX solution, but, in case you speak no old German, the available documentation is in German. NB: I haven't found the ellipse in the documentation, but you can contact the package author.